# How can i convert to integer numbers from string numbers in python

Tags: python, string, if-statement, type-conversion, integer

I want to change type my string numbers.
I wanna make them integer for comparing them which one is bigger.

```
numbers="4, 5, 29, 54, 4 ,0 ,-214, 542, -64, 1 ,-3, 6, -6"

ns=numbers.split()
nsi=[]
for i in range(len(ns)):
    ns[i]=int(ns[i])
    nsi.append(ns[i])


print(nsi)
```

I am getting error like this

```
ns[i]=int(ns[i])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4,'
```

Comment: Just `ns = [int(n) for n in numbers.split(',')]` works fine.

Comment: `list(map(int, numbers.split(",")))` also works.

Answer (score 0):

When you split the string it is split by whitespace... so with each number there is still the comma.

fixed:

```
numbers="4, 5, 29, 54, 4 ,0 ,-214, 542, -64, 1 ,-3, 6, -6"

ns=numbers.replace(",", "").split()
nsi=[]
for i in range(len(ns)):
    ns[i]=int(ns[i])
    nsi.append(ns[i])

print(nsi)
ns[i]=int(ns[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `split()` uses a whitespace as default split character. So there is still the comma left. You are able to specify the separator for the function with `split(', ')`.

See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) example on how split is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different separator in split().

```
numbers="4, 5, 29, 54, 4 ,0 ,-214, 542, -64, 1 ,-3, 6, -6"

ns=numbers.split(sep=",")
nsi=[]
for i in range(len(ns)):
   ns[i]=int(ns[i])
   nsi.append(ns[i])

print(nsi)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
numbers="4, 5, 29, 54, 4 ,0 ,-214, 542, -64, 1 ,-3, 6, -6"
ns = [int(i) for i in numbers.split(",")]
nsi=[]
for i in range(len(ns)):
   nsi.append(ns[i])
print(nsi)
```

or

```
numbers="4, 5, 29, 54, 4 ,0 ,-214, 542, -64, 1 ,-3, 6, -6"
ns = [int(i) for i in numbers.split(",")]
nsi=[]
nsi.extend(ns)
print(nsi)
```

That will cast all numbers in numbers list comperation to int's.
Output

```
[4, 5, 29, 54, 4, 0, -214, 542, -64, 1, -3, 6, -6]
```

Comment: Why the second loop? Why not just assign `nsi` to begin with?

Comment: Just because it was in the request

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I appreciate you:)

Comment: You welcome, welcome to SO. if the answer helped you please vote and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake.

Change this line

```
ns=numbers.split()
```

Into this

```
ns=numbers.split(", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.split(", ")` will give you an error when you try to convert the elements of the array into integers as numbers.split(", ") will give output as

```
ns = numbers.split(", ")
>>> print ns
['4', '5', '29', '54', '4 ,0 ,-214', '542', '-64', '1 ,-3', '6', '-6'] //'4 ->incorrect output
>>> print int(ns[4])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4 ,0 ,-214'
>>>
```

Instead you can do only

```
numbers.split(",")
```

and it will give you the correct integer array.
then typecast the elements for your purpose as int(...)

```
>>> ns = numbers.split(",")
>>> print ns
['4', ' 5', ' 29', ' 54', ' 4 ', '0 ', '-214', ' 542', ' -64', ' 1 ', '-3', ' 6', ' -6']
>>> a = int(ns[1])
>>> print a
5
```